# Samsung keyboard won't respect my input language choice in web browsers

Tags: samsung, keyboard, chrome-for-android, languages

I just got a new Samsung S20 and am working on getting it configured properly. The system language is English because I like all my technical things in English, but the input language I want is Swedish since I live in Sweden and that gives me some extra Swedish characters that I often need.

So for Samsung keyboard I've only installed Swedish as input language, and that works as expected for most places although it's still forcing me to use English as the primary input language when I'm using a web browser like the built-in or Chrome.

How can I make Samsung Keyboard respect my input language choice even in web browsers?

Comment: Did you try changing Chrome language settings to Swedish? See Chrome settings 3 dots menu on top right. Chrome is picking up English because it is the system language

Comment: If that doesn't help, please try changing [here](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/3333234?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en) (mobile seems para)

Comment: @beeshyams Nothing of this had any effect unfortunately.